# Trouble Installing Craft 2.5 on Windows 10 Using Wamp 2.5

Tags: install, installation, windows

I am trying to install Craft CMS 2.5 on a Windows 10 machine using WAMP 2.5.

I just downloaded both Craft and WAMP this morning — so both are fresh installs.

I believe I have done everything properly, but when I navigate to `localhost/sitename/public` I get the following message:

> Service Unavailable
>
> Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

If I try navigating to `localhost/sitename/public/admin` OR `localhost/sitename/admin` I get the following message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /sitename/admin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

These are the steps I took when setting up:

1. Created a folder in `wamp/www` called `sitename`
2. Copied the `craft` and `public` folders into the `sitename` folder
3. Changed `htaccess` to `.htaccess` (using windows command line)
4. Created database in phpmyadmin
5. Updated `db.php` in `craft/config` folder

(the only change I had to make was to add the database name — I left server as localhost, user as root and password blank.  I did change the tablePrefix to five different letters — i.e., no numbers or special characters)

I did NOT change the permissions on any of the app, config or storage folders for the simple reason that I do not know how to do that on Windows.

Unless the permissions are the problem, then I do not know why I am having this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get anything if you do `localhost/sitename/public/index.php/admin`?
It looks like your doc root is not the public folder and your .htaccess file is what does the rewrite of your urls to make them 'pretty'

Comment: @Moshe Can you add the solution that worked for you as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alec Ritson's comment solved the problem.  His advice was to try

```
localhost/sitename/public/index.php/admin
```

In other words, I had to add index.php to the URL (after public but before admin) and then everything worked fine.